# Why does "AND" operator results differ when writing it in different style in IBM Watson Discovery

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

When I run below queries on `Watson Discovery News (English)` collection

I am getting different results for

```
text:Google,text:IBM
```

[image: screenshot of query and result count for above query]

and

```
text:Google,IBM
```

[image: screenshot of query and result count for above query]

Reference
[AND operator](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/discovery?topic=discovery-query-operators#and)

What is the difference between those queries ?

Comment: Please provide more context on the data source and the results you are seeing.

Comment: @data_henrik I have added the screenshot, so when I run "And" operator query on ```Discovery news``` collection in above way , I get different set of documents

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the documentation suggests that

`text:Google,IBM` : Fetches documents where the text includes 'Google' and 'IBM'

`text:Google,text:IBM` : Fetches documents where the text includes 'Google' and 'text:IBM'